# About gravitational wave polarization in the detectors output

Tags: gravitational-waves

Gravitational wave detection with Michelson interferometers gives the gravitational wave strain(the amplitude) , in TT gauge frame we know there are two polarizations, now in some literature it says the detector response is the superposition( the linear combination) of the two polarization signals and in other it says the detected signal is just the plus polarization(look at Kip Thorne Blandford), it shows the photodetector response is directly proportional to it? , can someone resolve this ambiguity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The detector response $d(t)$ to a gravitational wave $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a combination of the *antenna pattern* of the detector $F_{+, \times}(\theta, \phi, t)$, the direction $\{\theta, \phi\}$ and arrival time $t$ of the gravitational wave, and the polarization. Decomposing the TT gauge perturbation into $+$ and $\times$ polarizations as $h_{ij} = h_+ e^+_{ij} + h_\times e^\times_{ij}$, where $e^{+,\times}_{ij}$ are *polarization tensors*, the detector response is given by
\begin{equation}
d(t) = h_+(t) F_+(\theta, \phi, t) + h_\times(t)F_\times (\theta, \phi, t)
\end{equation}

There are many places this is covered, such as vol 1 of Maggiore's book. An example free reference is Eq 1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.5421.

I assume the statement from Thorne and Blanford that you are mentioning is only intended to hold for a particular relative orientation of the gravitational wave and the detector. It sounds like they are probably considering a plane gravitational wave traveling in the direction orthogonal to the plane of the detector; then the response functions simplify so that $F_+=1$ and $F_\times=0$ (assuming that "$+$" has been defined to align with the arms of the interferometer).

Comment: So what is the sctual signal that we are detecting in the interferometer in th3 actual experiment? , is 8t just one single polarization? Or a combination?

Comment: @RubenPoghosyan It's the combination given in my answer and the references I cited.