# Detecting gravitational wave polarization

Tags: resource-recommendations, astronomy, gravitational-waves, polarization, gravitational-wave-detectors

We know that in TT gauge frame the gravitational wave has two polarization components, and the actual gravitational wave we are detecting is a linear combination of those two states , now a natural questions arises if can the current detectors make any sense if the two polarization states exist?, in other words can we detect gravitational wave polarization?, I have seen some references that say the current detectors are not sensitive to polarization and some claim that now with 3 detectors it is possible to detect the polarization.

But what is more interesting in most binary merger detection papers there is not much information about polarization, no one really talks about it

If there is any credible reference which proves and gives experimental results on gw polarization detection, please share it!, that would be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a gravitational wave (GW) source is detected by two detectors, with a time lag between the signals, then the source must sit on an annulus on the sky, drawn around an extension of the line joining the two detectors. The opening angle of the annulus is related to the lag and the speed of light (the speed of the GWs). The addition of a third detector then defines two more annuli between detectors 1 and 3 and detectors 2 and 3. The source must be located at the intersection of these annuli.

Each detector will then have a sensitivity to each of the two GW polarisations, which is a function of the source position on the sky (see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/737657/43351)). Providing the detectors are not all aligned so that they have the same sensitivities, then the three signal strengths, combined with the known sensitivity of each detector and the source position should yield the polarisation of the signal (e.g. see [section 3.1 of Raffai et al. 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3939)).

There are practical difficulties: Obviously, if the GW source position is uncertain then so too will be the polarisation. Likewise note that the two LIGO detectors are closely aligned in terms of their orientation in space, which is not ideal for discerning polarisation. There is also the problem that the VIRGO detector is somewhat less sensitive than the LIGO detectors and that most of the signals are very low signal-to-noise. A fledgling analysis along the lines you are looking for is described by [Abbott et al. 2017](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.141101) on the merging neutron star binary detected by all three interferometers.